# Dúvida com agrupamento de registro

Tags: sql, sql-server

No meu exemplo, tenho uma consulta que retornar 3 produtos sendo que os mesmos foram comprados em pedidos diferentes mais eu não preciso deste número de pedido. Então eu fiz desta forma:

```html
SELECT 
  c.prod_pk_id,           
 '61068276007702' as CNPJ,  
 'teste' AS FABRICANTE,  
 c.prod_pk_id AS CODIGOPRODUTO,  
 c.prod_nome AS NOMEPRODUTO,  
 case                         
   when CAST(CAST(c.PROD_COD_BARRAS AS BIGINT) AS VARCHAR)  = '0' then C.PROD_CODIGO_EXTERNO   
   when CAST(CAST(c.PROD_COD_BARRAS AS BIGINT) AS VARCHAR) <> ''  then CAST(CAST(c.PROD_COD_BARRAS AS BIGINT) AS VARCHAR) end as CODIGOBARRAS,                                  
   (b.pedip_qtde * 1000) AS QTDVENDIDO,  'BRL' as MOEDA,  
   CAST(a.pedi_dt_compra AS DATE) as DATA_VENDA,  
   b.PEDIP_VALOR_POR as TOTAL_PRODUTO,  
   ( cast( b.PEDIP_VALOR_POR  * b.pedip_qtde as Int) * 1000) AS TOTAL_PEDIDO,   
   (  select sum(PRODP_QTDE_ESTOQUE * 1000) from TB_PRODUTO_PRECO  where PRODP_FK_PROD_ID = c.prod_pk_id  ) as ESTOQUETOTAL     
   FROM TB_PEDIDO  A  
   INNER JOIN TB_CLIENTE G ON G.CLIE_PK_ID = A.PEDI_FK_CLIE_ID  
   inner join TB_PEDIDO_PRODUTO b on a.PEDI_PK_ID = b.PEDIP_FK_PEDI_ID  
   inner join TB_PRODUTO C on c.prod_pk_id = b.PEDIP_FK_PROD  
   inner join TB_FABRICANTE d on d.FABR_PK_ID = c.PROD_FK_FABR_ID  
   where d.fabr_nome like '%teste%'  
   and A.pedi_dt_compra between '2017-01-02' and '2017-01-03' 
   and c.prod_pk_id = 62168
   group by c.prod_pk_id,  
c.prod_nome,c.PROD_COD_BARRAS,C.PROD_CODIGO_EXTERNO,b.pedip_qtde,a.pedi_dt_compra,b.PEDIP_VALOR_POR,d.fabr_nome
```

me retorna os registros, eu gostaria de agrupar eles:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Para você conseguir agrupar, o conteúdo das linhas tem ser iguais. Se apesar da coluna estar contida na clausula GROUP BY e o banco não esta respeitando é sinal que tem conteúdo diferente entre linhas. Você terá de retirar essa coluna do select e do group by

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo, o conteúdo está igual, veja na imagem o resultado, o número do pedido não está na consulta

Comment: Faça um select desse select. Assim: SELECT * FROM ( select ...  )   A GROUP BY ..todos os campos que vierem.

Comment: Consultas que possuem cláusula GROUP BY com todas as colunas geralmente indicam código que necessita ser reescrito. No seu caso, sugiro que agrupe os pedidos de um mesmo produto antes de realizar as demais junções. Desta forma, na cláusula GROUP BY ficará o mínimo necessário.

Comment: Também é para agrupar os pedidos de um mesmo produto se, dentro do período de emissão do relatório, os pedidos para um mesmo produto forem feitos em dias diferentes? 
Como está declarada a coluna pedi_dt_compra? Se como datetime, contém somente data ou a data e a hora?

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite tudo bem ?

Veja como deve ser feito.

Também alterei o estoque total, da forma que estava feito, para cada registro que retornava no select ele fazia o select para ver o estoque, mudei para que trabalhe com um conjunto de dados que é muito mais eficiente.

```
SELECT 
C.PROD_PK_ID,           
'61068276007702' AS CNPJ,  
'TESTE' AS FABRICANTE,  
C.PROD_PK_ID AS CODIGOPRODUTO,  
C.PROD_NOME AS NOMEPRODUTO,  
CASE                         
    WHEN CAST(CAST(C.PROD_COD_BARRAS AS BIGINT) AS VARCHAR)  = '0' THEN 
        C.PROD_CODIGO_EXTERNO   
    WHEN CAST(CAST(C.PROD_COD_BARRAS AS BIGINT) AS VARCHAR) <> ''  THEN 
        CAST(CAST(C.PROD_COD_BARRAS AS BIGINT) AS VARCHAR) 
END AS CODIGOBARRAS,                                  
(B.PEDIP_QTDE * 1000) AS QTDVENDIDO,  
'BRL' AS MOEDA,  
CAST(A.PEDI_DT_COMPRA AS DATE) AS DATA_VENDA,  
B.PEDIP_VALOR_POR AS TOTAL_PRODUTO,  
( CAST( B.PEDIP_VALOR_POR  * B.PEDIP_QTDE AS INT) * 1000) AS TOTAL_PEDIDO,   
TV_ESTOQUE.ESTOQUETOTAL
FROM TB_PEDIDO  A  
INNER JOIN TB_CLIENTE G ON G.CLIE_PK_ID = A.PEDI_FK_CLIE_ID  
INNER JOIN TB_PEDIDO_PRODUTO B ON A.PEDI_PK_ID = B.PEDIP_FK_PEDI_ID  
INNER JOIN TB_PRODUTO C ON C.PROD_PK_ID = B.PEDIP_FK_PROD  
INNER JOIN TB_FABRICANTE D ON D.FABR_PK_ID = C.PROD_FK_FABR_ID
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT SUM(PRODP_QTDE_ESTOQUE * 1000) AS ESTOQUETOTAL,   PRODP_FK_PROD_ID 
            FROM TB_PRODUTO_PRECO               
          ) TV_ESTOQUE ON (TV_ESTOQUE.PRODP_FK_PROD_ID = C.PROD_PK_ID ) 
WHERE D.FABR_NOME LIKE '%TESTE%'  
AND A.PEDI_DT_COMPRA BETWEEN '2017-01-02' AND '2017-01-03' 
AND C.PROD_PK_ID = 62168
GROUP BY C.PROD_PK_ID, C.PROD_PK_ID, C.PROD_NOME , CASE                         
    WHEN CAST(CAST(C.PROD_COD_BARRAS AS BIGINT) AS VARCHAR)  = '0' THEN 
        C.PROD_CODIGO_EXTERNO   
    WHEN CAST(CAST(C.PROD_COD_BARRAS AS BIGINT) AS VARCHAR) <> ''  THEN 
        CAST(CAST(C.PROD_COD_BARRAS AS BIGINT) AS VARCHAR) 
END, A.PEDI_DT_COMPRA, B.PEDIP_VALOR_POR, TV_ESTOQUE.ESTOQUETOTA
```

Answer (score 0):

Eis proposta em que primeiro é realizado o agrupamento dos pedidos de um mesmo produto, na mesma data. Somente após esse agrupamento é que a consulta é executada.

```
-- código #1 v3
with Pedidos_Produto as (
SELECT PdPr.PEDIP_FK_PROD, 
       Cast(PdPr.pedi_dt_compra as date) as DataVenda,
       Sum(PdPr.pedip_qtde) as QtdVendido,
       Sum(PdPr.pedip_qtde * PdPr.PEDIP_VALOR_POR) as TotalVendido
  from TB_PEDIDO as Pd
       inner join TB_PEDIDO_PRODUTO as PdPr on Pd.PEDI_PK_ID = PdPr.PEDIP_FK_PEDI_ID
  where Pd.pedi_dt_compra between '2017-01-02' and '2017-01-03' 
  group by PdPr.PEDIP_FK_PROD, Cast(PdPr.pedi_dt_compra as date)
)
SELECT F.fabr_nome as Fabricante,
       Pr.prod_pk_id as [Código do produto],  
       Pr.prod_nome as [Nome do produto],  
       case when CAST(CAST(Pr.PROD_COD_BARRAS AS BIGINT) AS VARCHAR) <> ''  
            then CAST(CAST(Pr.PROD_COD_BARRAS AS BIGINT) AS VARCHAR) end as [Código de barras],
       PP.DataVenda, PP.QtdVendido, PP.TotalVendido,
       'BRL' as Moeda,
       (SELECT Sum(PRODP_QTDE_ESTOQUE) 
          from TB_PRODUTO_PRECO 
          where PRODP_FK_PROD_ID = Pr.prod_pk_id) as [Estoque total]
  from Pedidos_Produto as PP
       inner join TB_PRODUTO as Pr on Pr.prod_pk_id = PP.PEDIP_FK_PROD
       inner join TB_FABRICANTE as F on F.FABR_PK_ID = Pr.PROD_FK_FABR_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Um sub select resolve seu problema.

```
select * from
(
    SELECT 
      c.prod_pk_id,           
     '61068276007702' as CNPJ,  
     'teste' AS FABRICANTE,  
     c.prod_pk_id AS CODIGOPRODUTO,  
     c.prod_nome AS NOMEPRODUTO,  
     case                         
       when CAST(CAST(c.PROD_COD_BARRAS AS BIGINT) AS VARCHAR)  = '0' then C.PROD_CODIGO_EXTERNO   
       when CAST(CAST(c.PROD_COD_BARRAS AS BIGINT) AS VARCHAR) <> ''  then CAST(CAST(c.PROD_COD_BARRAS AS BIGINT) AS VARCHAR) end as CODIGOBARRAS,                                  
       (b.pedip_qtde * 1000) AS QTDVENDIDO,  'BRL' as MOEDA,  
       CAST(a.pedi_dt_compra AS DATE) as DATA_VENDA,  
       b.PEDIP_VALOR_POR as TOTAL_PRODUTO,  
       ( cast( b.PEDIP_VALOR_POR  * b.pedip_qtde as Int) * 1000) AS TOTAL_PEDIDO,   
       (  select sum(PRODP_QTDE_ESTOQUE * 1000) from TB_PRODUTO_PRECO  where PRODP_FK_PROD_ID = c.prod_pk_id  ) as ESTOQUETOTAL     
       FROM TB_PEDIDO  A  
       INNER JOIN TB_CLIENTE G ON G.CLIE_PK_ID = A.PEDI_FK_CLIE_ID  
       inner join TB_PEDIDO_PRODUTO b on a.PEDI_PK_ID = b.PEDIP_FK_PEDI_ID  
       inner join TB_PRODUTO C on c.prod_pk_id = b.PEDIP_FK_PROD  
       inner join TB_FABRICANTE d on d.FABR_PK_ID = c.PROD_FK_FABR_ID  
       where d.fabr_nome like '%teste%'  
       and A.pedi_dt_compra between '2017-01-02' and '2017-01-03' 
       and c.prod_pk_id = 62168
)c
group by c.prod_pk_id, c.CNPJ, c.FABRICANTE, c.CODIGOPRODUTO, 
c.NOMEPRODUTO, c.CODIGOBARRAS, c.QTDVENDIDO, c.MOEDA, c.DATA_VENDA, c.TOTAL_PRODUTO,
c.TOTAL_PEDIDO, c.ESTOQUETOTAL
```

Veja se eu não esqueci nenhum campo no group by.